# Smooth scrolling in JavaFX TableView

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I am writing a small chat application in Kotlin with TornadoFX that works so far.
I am currently trying to make it more visually appealing when receiving new messages.
The messages are in a `TableView` (sender - message) but scrolling to new messages isn't smooth like I would like.

The snippet where I need help is relatively short:

```
addEventHandler(ScrollToEvent.ANY) {
  it.consume()
  timeline {
  val keyValue = KeyValue(/* property to change */, /* target value */, Interpolator.EASE_OUT)
    keyframe(0.25.seconds) {
      this.plusAssign(keyValue)
    }
  }
}
```

In general I need help figuring out which property to change and what the target should be in this line:

```
KeyValue(/* property to change */, /* target value */, Interpolator.EASE_OUT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution.
One needs to lookup the `ScrollBar` the `TableView` provides, once enough rows are present (and when scrolling actually does anything).

From [TornadoFX JavaFX Sync Scroll across tableviews](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41463457/4867727), I adapted the lookup and came up with this, working, code:

```
addEventHandler(ScrollToEvent.ANY) {
  it.consume()
  timeline {
    val scrollBar = lookupAll(".scroll-bar").first() as ScrollBar
    val keyValue = KeyValue(scrollBar.valueProperty(), scrollBar.max, Interpolator.EASE_OUT)
    keyframe(0.5.seconds) {
      this.plusAssign(keyValue)
    }
  }
}
```